# Zxing PDF417 Recognition

Tags: c#, barcode, zxing, pdf417, zxing.net

I'm having some trouble getting Zxing to recognise a PDF417 code like the following:
[image: Example code]

I've tried on a few other large examples and none of them seem to be working either. It works fine on smaller samples though. I was just wondering if Zxing was capable of working with these sorts of images or if I'd have to try another framework?

Answer (score 0):

*Zxing* is more than capable recognising PDF417 barcodes.

You might get more luck with the `BarcodeReader.TryHarder` settings which will use more CPU cycles.

The problem is not with *Zxing* is more likely having trouble with the image quality due to the size of the image. Ie PDF417 requires at least one of those funny little lines on the sides of your image to be identifiable, otherwise it will fail. from looking at your image it looks like either the paper is very bad quality, or your image is very bad quality.

However, once again, i think this is your optics not *Zxing*. i just tested this with my phone and xzing, and i couldn't get that image to work. however i use this app in production all over our warehouse with pdf417 of all shapes and sizes and it works flawlessly

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and get a better quality picture and see if that helps